# Only count same moving object/circle once in a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have several videos where circles move in rows from bottom to top. At the moment I manage to count the circles in the top most row in each frame. But because every video has a different row speed, some circles are scanned 2-3 times before they disappear from the video.

```
#draw circle on blur-window if circle is in upper row
        for i in all_circles_blured[0, :]:
            if i[1] in range(y_posrange1, y_posrange2) and i[0] in range(x_posrange1, x_posrange2):
                #print(i, TabNumber)
                TabNumber += 1
                cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 5)  # draw the outer circle
                cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 155, 0), 2)  # draw the center of the circle
                cv2.putText(blur, str(TabNumber), (i[0] - 10, i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
```

I tried to save the x and y coordinate and compare them with circles from the previous frame but it does not work properly.

```
# draw circle on blur-window if circle is in upper row
        for i in all_circles_blured[0, :]:
            if i[1] in range(y_posrange1, y_posrange2) and i[0] in range(x_posrange1, x_posrange2):
                #compare to previous circles and look for maxdistance 5
                if i[1] in range(i0_prior_frame, i0_prior_frame+5) and i[1] in range(i1_prior_frame, i1_prior_frame+5 ):
                    print("same circle detected")
                else:
                    TabNumber += 1
                    cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 5)  # draw the outer circle
                    cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 155, 0), 2)  # draw the center of the circle
                    cv2.putText(blur, str(TabNumber), (i[0] - 10, i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                i0_prior_frame = i[0]
                i1_prior_frame = i[1]
```

I guess the problem is that with i0_priorframe I only store one circle and not all circles per frame?

Answer (score 0):

PyImageSearch is my favorite resource for this kind of thing https://www.pyimagesearch.com/.

This guide may be especially helpful: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/23/simple-object-tracking-with-opencv/

Persistently tracking all the circles *will* be difficult and not super straightforward.

I started writing an object tracking library: https://github.com/bherbruck/simple-tracker  It tracks objects by giving it all the detected objects in a frame and determines if an object is the same one if the movement is within a threshold.